# Finding left-hand derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the left-hand derivative of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$  at the point $x=0$?

$1)-\frac{\sqrt2}2\qquad\qquad2)-\sqrt2\qquad\qquad3)\frac{\sqrt2}2\qquad\qquad4)\sqrt2$

To solve the problem I tried taking derivative by implying chain rule:

$$f'(x)=\left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)'\times\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\times\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$

But when I plug in $x=0$ I get $0$ . I don't know why this method doesn't work.

Comment: When plotting it on wolfram alpha it looks like it doesn't have solution at all. it's looks discouncus plus $\frac{1}{2(1-(1-x^2)^{0.5})^{0.5}}$ at $0$ is $\frac{1}{0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{x} &= -
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}}\\
&=-\sqrt{\lim_{x\to 0^- }\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}}\\
&=-\sqrt{\lim_{x\to 0^- }\frac{x^2}{x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2)}}}\\
&=-\sqrt{\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\
&= -\frac{\sqrt2}{2}
\end{align}

Remark:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}} &=-\frac12\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\\
&=-\frac12 \sqrt{\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x^2}}\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt2}2
\end{align}

Note the derivative does not exist though the left-hand derivative and right-hand derivative exist.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you plug in $0$ to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\times\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$ you get $$\frac{0}{\sqrt{1-0^2}}\times\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-0^2}}}=0\times\frac{1}{0}$$ so you get undefined not $0$.